# CSS/HTML checklist content alignment

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I'm having difficulty with the following code - everything works as I wish it EXCEPT the contents of the check boxes. The ticks and crosses are too low.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here please? I admit I hacked this code from several sources and glued it together, so I'm more than happy to admit I have misunderstood something or other.

Thanks!

```css
.checkbox {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 36px;
  text-align: left;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

.checkbox:before {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  content: "\2715\0020";
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked+.checkbox:before {
  color: #f3f3f3;
  background-color: #abcdef;
  content: "\2714\0020";
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <form>
    <input id="option1" type="checkbox">
    <label class="checkbox" for="option1">Unchecked</label>
    <input id="option2" type="checkbox" checked>
    <label class="checkbox" for="option2">Checked, changeable</label>
    <input id="option3" type="checkbox" checked disabled>
    <label class="checkbox" for="option3">Checked, fixed</label>
    <input id="option4" type="checkbox" checked disabled>
    <label class="checkbox" for="option4">Checked, fixed</label>
    <input id="option5" type="checkbox">
    <label class="checkbox" for="option5">Unchecked</label>
  </form>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add **line-height** to `.checkbox:before{...}`  set it to 20px, or play this number,

```
.checkbox:before {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    content: "\2715\0020";
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: I swear by all the gods I already tried this and it didn't work! Now it does :-) Magic really does exist in this world. Thanks you!

Comment: where did you add this code? try replace `.checkbox:before{/*your previous code*/}` with the solution I've provided

Answer (score 0):

Add `line-height: 1.2;` to your `.checkbox:before`:

```
.checkbox:before {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    content: "\2715\0020";
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 1.2; /* add this*/ 
}
```

Comment: I like this answer, rather than adding a fixed size. Seems more adaptable to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```css
.checkbox {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 36px;
  text-align: left;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

.checkbox:before {
  display: inline;
  padding:2px;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  content: "\2715\0020";
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked+.checkbox:before {
  color: #f3f3f3;
  background-color: #abcdef;
  content: "\2714\0020";
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <form>
    <input id="option1" type="checkbox">
    <label class="checkbox" for="option1">Unchecked</label>
    <input id="option2" type="checkbox" checked>
    <label class="checkbox" for="option2">Checked, changeable</label>
    <input id="option3" type="checkbox" checked disabled>
    <label class="checkbox" for="option3">Checked, fixed</label>
    <input id="option4" type="checkbox" checked disabled>
    <label class="checkbox" for="option4">Checked, fixed</label>
    <input id="option5" type="checkbox">
    <label class="checkbox" for="option5">Unchecked</label>
  </form>
</section>
```

Comment: Aah yes, took me a bit to spot the fix. Note to self: look up difference between "inline" and "inline-block". Thanks!

Comment: Great,@bill-parker  if you find this answer solves your question, then accept the answer by clicking the tick box which is left to this answer